# Is it possible to pro-drop/null anaphora in Turkish without any reference to the pronoun at all?

Tags: anaphora, ellipsis, pronouns

My question is inspired from: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466749/what-do-we-call-the-process-of-dropping-the-subject-at-the-beginning-of-a-senten

> Person 1 >> "Hey, when are you coming over?"

> Person 2 >> "[I will] **Probably** be there at around 14:00."

So in English there is this process where you can drop the subject and there is a thing such as an inferred subject. Other examples like:

> (I am) **Going** to the shop now. 
> (I) **Was** hit on by this guy

> I was shot by him/her 
> Ben onun tarafından **vur-ul-du-m**

Infinitive: vurmak 
Conjugated in the example above as verb-causative suffix-definite past-1st pers.

In turkish the syntax word order is as follows:

> Ben onun tarafından vuruldum 
> I-his-by-was shot

Since turkish has the pronoun suffix marker -m in the verb for the first person singular, “ben” the pronoun can be omitted as follows:

> “ “ onun tarafından vuruldu**m** 
> His-by-I was shot

Turkish uses the possessive case for “him” in this example.

Now is it possible to remove the person suffix marker and have it still refer to “I” first person:

> (ben) onun tarafından vuruldu(m) = (I) was shot by him/her

But the problem is that in Turkish, the 3rd person takes no ending:

So basically it can be translated as

> (O) Onun tarafından vuruldu.

O is the pronoun for he/she in turkish and can be removed

> He/she was shot by him/her.

So is it possible to pro-drop in Turkish in a causative sentence without any reference to the pronoun, i.e an inferred subject/null anaphora?

Note: I am aware **Turkish does allow some pronoun dropping but usually the marker at the end of the verb signifes the tense.**

Comment: Since the absence of a personal suffix on the predicate/predicative is meaningful in Turkish and marks the 3rd person subject, dropping that suffix together with the explicit subject _inevitably_ results in that utterance having the 3rd person as the subject. Or in case you mean another subject than the 3rd p., the sentence will be ungrammatical, in any case you'll fail to fulfill your communication goal: you won't transmit the information intended.

Comment: @YellowSky +1 I see. It is strange that in Turkish that the predicate requires a grammatical personal suffix while in other similar Altaic Languages like Korean and Japanese don’t even require at all, for example in Japanese “I went to tokyo” would be *Toukyou ni ikimashita* - which basically translates as *Tokyo, towards, went*.

Comment: @aesking Note that the idea of an "Altaic" family isn't widely accepted nowadays.

Comment: @aesking And even those who do believe in an Altaic family generally don’t believe Japanese is part of it. Besides, Japanese doesn’t _have_ personal endings, so you can’t _not_ drop it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Those who believe Korean is part of the Altaic family, believe just as much as they do about Japanese being a part of it. I suggest you read “Georg, Stefan; Michalove, Peter A.; Ramer, Alexis Manaster; Sidwell, Paul J. (1999). "Telling general linguists about Altaic". Journal of Linguistics. 35 (1): 65–98. doi:10.1017/S0022226798007312”, of those who believe Japanese (Japonic language) is part of the Altaic family. Secondly, even tho Japanese doesn’t take *personal suffix endings* it is mostly part of the agglutinative family such as Hungarian, Turkish, Korean, and Swahili.

Comment: The phenomenon in English is not "pro-drop". It's called [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), and it deletes any predictable particle -- pronouns, auxiliaries, dummies, contractions, prepositions, whatever, as long as it's predictable by syntactic rule (and therefore unnecessary semantically). It happens in speech, not writing (except dialog, where it's prominent), so online searches aren't any help.

Comment: @jlawler in English it’s called “Conversational Deletion” but in other languages not so, my question is about Turkish.

Answer (score 3):

> So is it possible to pro-drop in Turkish in a causative sentence without any reference to the pronoun, i.e an inferred subject/null anaphora?

Short answer, no. The subject marking on the verb is mandatory.

As you mention, "the 3rd person takes no ending"—in other words, the third person singular marker is ∅ (nothing). So if you leave off all other markings, listeners will interpret it as 3S.

But even in languages where none of the markers are ∅, such as Latin or Swahili, it's common for the marking to be mandatory; leaving it off is ungrammatical. You can't just say **amā-v-* or **-li-penda* "loved"; you need *amā-v-ī* or *ni-li-penda* "I loved". (Or *amā-v-it* or *a-li-penda* "he loved", etc.)

Comment: The same is true in English, really – it’s just that in English, most personal markets are zero, so it’s hard to tell. But if you use a verb like the present of _to be_, it becomes clear that you cannot just use some abstract, unmarked form: you have to chose _am_, _are_ or _is_ or leave out the verb altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can! I’m fluent in turkish and my parents are both Turks.

It is possible to do so with a pretext or situational environment for example if you were with a friend and she asks:

Q: **Köpeği nerede gördün?** (Where did you see the dog?)

You can answer with many options:

- Omit the verb

A: *Kopeği sinemada* (gördüm).

In English this would be “The dog, -at the cinema”. This wouldn’t make sense in English but makes perfect sense in Turkish.

- Omit the verb and object

A: (Kopeği) *sinemada* (gördüm).

In English this would be a typical response “at cinema/at the cinema” to “where did you see it/him/her?”

It’s important to note that this is only possible if the context is established, for example if I was informally texting a friend on the phone or casually speaking to a friend in person. In formal situations, such as writing essays it would be ungrammatical to leave out the predicate.

Interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Turkish very well, but what you want is possible through using of the verb form of the state with high levels of the ambiguity, so:
(I am) going to the shop now, can be translated as:
(Ben) Shop'e varmakta (oluyorum).

As mentioned above, I don't know Turkish very well, so I don't know what is prescribed by Turkish usus (sic! in literary language) - can you really drop this oluyorum or not, but there are more analytical Turkic languages and dialects, where this is possible. Even more - some clauses need an impersonal part in it by formulae like:
impersonal part, personal part; where second part is contextual for the first part.

So, I don't know why your question is downvoted.

Comment: I don’t know why my question is downvoted either, probably some very *childish* people from a previous SE community I’m from: English SE.

Comment: But thanks for your insight! It’s as I suspected from the recent answer that was posted.